# How to backport a bug fix?

Tags: bug-reporting

I see a bugfix, that I need, in launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1032456) for the package for cups, but, if I understand things correctly, it is built for 12.10, and I am on 12.04.

Is it still possible to install it? If so, how can I do this?

Is it unwise to install it?

Will the fix eventually become available in the 12.04 updates if I can wait long enough, or am I forced to upgrade away from the LTS version?

Comment: I would wait.  If it's a security fix, it should become available in backports.  If it's a general fix/feature, it may or may not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** This answer is obsolete. The bug was fixed on August 7, 2012, and can/should be fixed with the regular Update Manager updates. See [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173229/why-did-my-canon-or-epson-printer-stop-working-after-a-recent-update-on-12-04) if you would like to install it manually.

---

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1032456) is special in two ways from a lot of other garden-variety bugs ;)

- It's a regression (when an update causes something that was working just fine earlier to stop working)
- It's "critical" importance (anything that causes most Canon printers to print out half-pages should!)

So, it will definitely show up in 12.04 updates soon, considering that it took 3 days to fix it for Quantal.

**I strongly advise** waiting for the above. In theory, you can install the Quantal debs, but CUPS is not a solitary package -- it has tons of dependencies which you'd also need to install manually. In short, this route can get VERY messy.

In the meanwhile, the more practical option is to downgrade to the previous CUPS version which works just fine. Do this with:

```
sudo apt-get install cups=1.5.2-9ubuntu1
```

To prevent upgrading it until a fixed version is released, hold it with:

```
sudo sh -c "echo cups hold | dpkg --set-selections"
```

and keep an eye on the bug report page. When a fix is available, you can install it and release the hold with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cups
```

Comment: typically, bugfixes don't get backported even for critical bugs, unless its nominated for Precise and someone SRU's it. It's currently "Triaged" against Precise, but if someone were fixing it, they'd be assigned.  Someone'd have to take the assignment, apply the patch, generate the debdiffs, upload those debdiffs, and then get the package uploaded into precise-proposed.

Comment: True enough, but if you read the bug report and notice *who* is fixing it and how serious they seem to consider it, do you really think this won't somehow make it back into Precise soon ;)

Comment: there's nobody assigned to the Precise bug right now, last I checked an hour ago.

Comment: Should someone have been assigned to the Quantal bug which the maintainer-cum-upstream-maintainer fixed?

Comment: This bug has now been assigned to someone for Precise.  Apparently, there's an SRU freeze as well, so... not sure when this'll get in there.  Probably *after* the end of august

Comment: Well, until then, I can't print!!   Really hard to wait. I can't downgrade either as I get this error "ln: accessing `/usr/lib/cups/backend-available/ipp14': No such file or directory
"

Comment: Wait, the developer has made it available in his PPA.  I just downloaded it and it works.  Problem solved thanks all.

Comment: @ubnewbie2: thanks for that important update! I am on the road and didn't check the bug report after I posted the "eta on precise?" request. I will update the answer in a few hours. All's well that ends well!

Comment: @LordofTime: [Ooh looky, they approved and released an SRU *that same day*!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1032456/comments/21) :P